# Java socket program unable to read large amount of data at a time

Tags: java, sockets

I have written a socket program using `read()` and `write()`.
Whenever I want to send large data using `write()`. I am unable to recieve data at a time. Means my data is divided into two sections so how can I send large amount of data? or read the data at 1 time?

Also I am unable to know whether this is the problem of `write()` or `read()`

Thanks
Bapi

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your question yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780373/read-and-write-method-for-large-data-in-socket-communication-does-not-work-reliab

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you tried from the answers you received yesterday and we can go from there.

Comment: I have tried all the approach from yester day.
I have also applied thread sleep for 1 sec it works fine but its but reliable as per my network concern.

Answer (score 2):

read() is only guaranteed to read 1 byte, anything more than that is a bonus.

A common way to handle this is to use DataOutputStream and DataInputStream to send the size of the "block" you want.

```
public static void write(DataOutput out, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(bytes.length);
    out.write(bytes);
}

public static byte[] read(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    int len = in.readInt();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    in.readFully(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not even guaranteed to read that much... the socket might be in non-blocking mode; <smile>.